# Why sendmail is accepting mails for hostname not present in local-host-names file?

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

I have following line in my `cf` file

`Fw/etc/mail/local-host-names`

and following lines in `local-host-names` file

```
mydomain.com
hostname.mydomain.com
```

but when I send mail to `mailaddress@otherhost.mydomain.com`, sendmail is accepting mails for it. otherhost.mydomain.com resolves to one of the private IP address. What could be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "is accepting"? Do you mean it's delivering the mails locally?

Comment: No if I try to send mail by accessing SMTP using telnet, for rcpt to it says recipient ok. It should say user unknown right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your prompt type:

```
$ sendmail -bt
> $=w
```

$=w is a class that contains all the names sendmail considers local. These include those listed in `/etc/mail/local-host-names` and those in `/etc/hosts` that sendmail considers local after examining the machine's network interfaces.

Comment: thanks a lot. sendmail is considering `otherhost.mydomain.com` as local after observing network interface. It is a PTR record for IP addresses on one of the ethernet interfaces.

Comment: There is an option to turn off "auto detection/adding" local email domains (DontProbeInterfaces).

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip thanks a lot for your suggestion. Yes, I verified `DontProbeInterfaces` is False in my case.

Comment: Is otherhost.mydomain.com a CNAME DNS record? YES => sendmail rewrites CNAMEs (DNS aliases) to "true names".