# How can I force sendmail to use SMTP instead of internal relay?

Tags: sendmail

I have a web server that was blacklisted from sending email because it was responding to `SMTP HELO` with `localhost.localdomain` instead of the domain name of my server (we'll call it `example.com`). I was able to get the server to respond to the `HELO` with `example.com` by removing `localhost.localdomain` from my `/etc/hosts` file. However, now any time I try to send email to an address with the same domain name, sendmail is attempting to deliver the message locally instead of sending it via SMTP to our actual mail server (which is hosted at Rackspace).

I followed the advice here: [Why sendmail is accepting mails for hostname not present in local-host-names file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/495600/why-sendmail-is-accepting-mails-for-hostname-not-present-in-local-host-names-fil) and ran

```
echo '$=w' | sendmail -bt
```

And got:

```
[mail]
[162.243.XX.XXX]
mail
[mail.example.com]
mail.example.com
localhost
[127.0.0.1]
example.com
```

From what I understand, sendmail considers all of those domains local. I set `DontProbeInterfaces=True` in my `sendmail.cf` file. Now when I run

```
sendmail -bt
$=w
```

I get:

```
localhost
[127.0.0.1]
example.com
```

I also tried removing `example.com` from `/etc/mail/local-host-names`, but sendmail still thinks that `example.com` is local. How can I get sendmail to stop attempting local mail delivery for `example.com` email addresses?

**EDIT:**

```
echo '$j' | sendmail -bt
```

produces

`example.com`

**EDIT:**

I tried changing the hostname from `example.com` to `example`, but now my `SMTP HELO` response is `localhost` and it takes several minutes to send an email. According to this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sendmail-is-slow-to-send-mail `sendmail` expects `hostname` to be the FQDN, but I'm being told that it should *never* be the FQDN. Which is it?

This is in my `mail.log`:

```
Jul 28 16:40:01 localhost sm-msp-queue[1679]: My unqualified host name (localhost) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jul 28 16:41:01 localhost sm-msp-queue[1679]: unable to qualify my own domain name (localhost) -- using short name
```

Comment: Could you include results produced by `echo '$j' | sendmail -bt`? Does it produce `example.com`? YES => change name reported by `hostname --fqdn` to www.example.com.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip yes, `echo '$j' | sendmail -bt` produces `example.com`. I tried `hostname --fqdn www.example.com` but it just gave me the "Usage:" instructions. Also, I don't use `www.`, does that matter?

Comment: sendmail? May I see your time machine, dude?

Comment: @poige My personal recommendation for sendmail (sendmail-8) is "keep" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the comment by @poige my sanity was restored:

Remove `sendmail`. Install `postfix`. There's a good tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Then edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and remove the fully qualified domain name from the `mydestination` parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Fix your server's hostname. [No server should ever have a hostname equal to the naked domain name](https://serverfault.com/a/599725/126632); this is but one of the many problems which occurs when you do this.

Comment: I tried changing the hostname, but now my `SMTP HELO` response is `localhost` and it takes several minutes to send an email message.

Comment: Are you trying to use a Debian-based system?!

Comment: Yes, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: Better see the other answer, then; Debian-based systems that don't use systemd don't handle their own hostnames properly. The workaround is to reconfigure sendmail as given in Andrzej's answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your case Sendmail adds auto-configured "this host (email) name" (`$j`) to list of local email domains (`$=w`).  Sendmail uses name reported by `hostname --fqdn`.

**Recomended fixes:**
[Do not use "named domain" as hostname (as suggested in Michael reply)](https://serverfault.com/a/709145/163277)
**OR**
[Change name used by sendmail as "this host mail name"](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html)